# Error on Linq To Entities method contains NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've checked other questions and I believe this should work:

```
private static List<Duck> GetDucks(this DataServiceContext ctx, params int[] ids)
{
    return ctx.CreateQuery<Duck>("Ducks").Where(x => ids.Contains(x.DuckID)).ToList();
}
```

I got a *NotSupportedException: The method 'Contains' is not supported.*

I changed the query to

```
Where(x => ids.Any(id => id == x.DuckID)
```

I received the message: *The method 'Any' is not supported when MaxProtocolVersion is less than '3.0*'

I then constructed the DataServiceContext a different way:

```
public static  DataServiceContext Context
{
    get { return new DataServiceContext(baseUri, DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3); }
}
```

I then received the message: *NotSupportedException: The source parameter for the 'Any' method has to be either a navigation or a collection property*

I think I could do with some advice before going any further.

**EDIT**

I did use MaxProtocolVersion 3 both client and server side.

In any case, this particular error message has gone away for now as I am no longer trying to return a subset of data. I simply get the full list of entities up front to work with (though this will need further consideration/optimization). I mistakenly believed that if I had a temp DataServiceContext that was empty I would have to retrieve the entities I wanted to update and then save them back (influenced by various examples on performing updates I found). Of course the method *AttachTo(EntitySetName, entity)* is the correct solution. Then you can call *UpdateObject(entity)* prior to *TempContext.SaveChanges()*.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace? This feels like a problem with WCF Data Services.

Comment: @Pawel It's not a problem with WCF as I can use the where clause without using the Contains method such as x.DuckID == 5

Comment: I don't know. Show the stack trace. For instance this message "The method 'Any' is not supported when MaxProtocolVersion is less than '3.0'" is for sure returned from WCF Data Services so I don't know where the NotSupportedException comes from - Data Services or EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have learned it looks like LINQ support in this scenario is limited, though I still do not know why contains does not work on a DataServiceQuery. The MSDN documentation suggests it is supported. Queries to the DataServiceContext resolve urls in [OData format](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/):

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Category(1)/Products?$top=2&$orderby=name

The solution I used - adding a WCF Data Service operation/method:

```
    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<Thing> GetThingsByID(string ids)
    {
        return CurrentDataSource.Things.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ThingID.ToString())).AsQueryable();
    }
```

The above should allow me to filter:

[WCF Data Service operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788.aspx)

[Calling Service Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230677.aspx)

I pass in ids as CSVs as only primitive data types may be passed as parameters

Note:
Contains works on the DBContext.